# using ruby elasticsearch gem, how can I query with multiple paramaters

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I basically want to do a search which is:

```
select all from index_name where tag = 'big data' and city = 'tokyo'
```

The code is:

```
require "elasticsearch"
client = Elasticsearch::Client.new log: true
client.search index: 'candidates', body:
{
  query: {

    match: {
          tags: search_term
           }
        }
}
```

which works fine. When, however, I change to something like:

```
match: {
          tags: search_term, city: 'Tokyo'
           }
```

that is to say just adding another parameter I get an error.

I have tried adding

```
filter: {
            city: 'Tokyo'
       }
```

also with no success.

Thanks guys, what's the best way forward here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the Elasticsearch [query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html). For a simple "A and B" query you need to simply use a [`bool / must` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html). Replace your body with this:

```
client.search index: 'candidates', body:
{
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          match: {
            tags: 'big data'
          }
        },
        {
          match: {
            city: 'tokyo'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, getting a syntax error:
search.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you have now?

Comment: it works, sorry I must have had a glitch in there somewhere. I am very grateful to you, thank you.